# Can `snprintf()` read out of bounds when a string argument is not null-terminated?

Tags: c, string, printf

I have the following piece of code, which a colleague claims may contain an out-of-bounds read, which I do not agree with. Could you help settle this argument and explain why?

```
char *test_filename = malloc(Size + 1);
sprintf(test_filename, "");

if (Size > 0 && Data)
  snprintf(test_filename, Size + 1, "%s", Data);
```

where `Data` is a non-null-terminated string of type `const uint8_t *Data` and `Size` is the size of `Data`, i.e., number of bytes in `Data`, of type `size_t`.

It may read out-of-bounds because the format string is `%s`, perhaps?

Comment: If the unterminated source string has a length of 4 and you pass 5, how would `snprintf` know to stop at 4?

Comment: `if (Size > 0 && !Data)` -->> snprintf is only executed if Size greater than zero and Data IS NULL.

Comment: @wildplasser ah yeah, don't mind that problem. Thanks for noting

Comment: Lookup in the manual what snprintf() returns, especially in the case where the resulting string's length would exceed the second argument (Size+1).

Comment: *a colleague claims may contain an out-of-bounds read* And there's **nothing** you can do about it since you're doing string processing that assumes strings are properly terminated.  The problem is **in any code that passes a non-NUL-terminated string to your function**.

Comment: @AndrewHenle That is not obvious, since the [opengroup description of snprintf()](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/snprintf.html) says "output bytes beyond the n-1st **shall be discarded".** You have, as wildplasser suggests, to read on to the return value to understand that snprintf() actually *does read* the excess source bytes (for diagnostic purposes); it just doesn't *write* them. So yes, unless there is an intervening 0 byte it will read the Size+1th byte, which is out-of-bounds (the OP states that Size is the number of bytes at Date), and return Size+1.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica You're misunderstanding my comment.  **Of course** `snprintf()` will read excess bytes if the "string argument is not `NUL`-terminated".  But the **problem** is caused by passing in an improperly-terminated string.  Note that an argument that is not properly terminated is **not a string**.  A string - by definition - must have a proper `'\0'` termination.  If the calling code doesn't ensure that, the problem is in the **calling** code.  "Here's my function that processes a string."  "Ok, here's something **that ISN'T a string!**"

Comment: I didn't misunderstand. It is just that it is not obvious that s**n**printf() actually reads more than **n** bytes, since it does not copy them. You can of course provide non-terminated strings to functions which don't do excess reads; why not?

Comment: Not only that, if `Data` in the example is the standard `[unsigned] char *` used to refer to a string, there's no way for the function to tell where it's supposed to end if it's not properly terminated.  Again - the problem is in the calling code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your colleague is correct. Perhaps unintuitively, `snprintf(test_filename, Size + 1, "%s", Data)` is guaranteed to read bytes starting at `Data` until a 0 byte is encountered, in your case typically resulting in an out-of-bounds read.

It will only *write* `Size` of these bytes to `test_filename` and null terminate them, respecting the size limit of the destination; but it will continue to *read* on. The reason for that is a design choice which enables the caller to determine the needed *destination* size for dynamic allocation before anything is actually written: `snprintf()` returns the number of bytes *which would be written if the destination had infinite space.* This feature is supposed to be used with a destination size of 0 (and potentially a null pointer as the destination). This functionality is useful for arguments which are not strings: With numbers etc. the size of the output is difficult to predict (e.g. locale dependent) and best left to the function at run time.

At the same time the return value indicates whether the output was truncated: If it is greater or equal to the size parameter, not all of the input was used in the output. In your case, what was left out were the bytes starting a `Data[Size]` and ending with the first 0 byte, or a segmentation fault ;-).

Suggestion for a fix: First of all it is unclear why you would use the `printf` family to print a string; simply copy it. And then Andrew has a point in his comments that since `Data`is not null terminated it is not really a string (even if all bytes are printable); so don't start fiddling with `strcpy` and friends but simply `memcpy()` the bytes, and null terminate manually.

Oh, and the preceding `sprintf(test_filename, "");` does not serve any discernible purpose. If you want to write a null byte to `*Data`, simply do so; but since you are not using `strcat`, which would rely on a terminated destination string to extend, it is quite unnecessary.

Answer (score -1):

from the MAN page for `snprintf()`

```
The  functions  snprintf()  and  vsnprintf()  write  at most size bytes (including the terminating null byte ('\0')) to str.
```

Note the `at most size bytes`

This means that `snprintf()` will stop transferring bytes after the parameter `Size` bytes are transferred.

this statement;

```
sprintf(test_filename, "");
```

is completely unneeded and has no effect on the operation of the second call to `snprintf()`

If you want to result in a 'proper' string, suggest:

```
char *test_filename = calloc( sizeof( char ), Size + 1);

if (Size > 0 && Data)
    snprintf(test_filename, Size, "%s", Data);
```

however, the function: `snprintf()` keeps reading until a NUL byte is encountered.  This can create problems, upto and including a seg fault event.

The function: `memcpy()` is made for this kind of job.  Suggest replacing the call to `snprintf()` with

```
memcpy( test_filename, Data, Size );
```

Comment: The problem in using `memcpy()` is you need to know the length to copy.  If the value is passed to a function just by address under the assumption that it refers to a string, there's no way for the function to know the length without going searching for the a `NUL` character.

Comment: It matters not about where some embedded NUL char might be in the source string.  `Size` bytes will be copied and there is room in the destination buffer for all the `Size` bytes.

Comment: If the source address is only available as a address because it's supposed to be a string, there's no way to use `memcpy()`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle,  the question states that the parameter `Size` is the number of bytes to be copied.  *Size is the size of Data, i.e., number of bytes in Data, of type size_t.*  Well, the number of bytes in a `size_t` is the same as a `long unsigned int` which, on my 64 bit ubuntu linux is 8 bytes. so your asking about some multiple of 8 byte units.  Please clarify